# Different languages following the same pattern to name the same object

Tags: terminology

A drawer is something one draws out of a piece of furniture. Likewise in French with *tiroir* coming from the verb *tirer* and in Japanese 引き出し from 引く. Is there a word for such a phenomenon: several languages naming the same object (or concept) following the same pattern?

Comment: When one language borrows the metaphor from another, but uses its own lexicon to build the new word, that is called a _calque_. But I don't know a word for when several languages independent (as far as we know) come up with a form of expression. A well known case is _count_ and its congeners, which have meanings around both numbering, and telling a story. This is true in French as well, but also in German (and in fact the word _tell_, related to German _Zahlen_, also has both meanings, though the number meaning only survives in a few words in English). Also in Russian and Hebrew!

Comment: @ColinFine Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @ColinFine In my example there is a self-evident logic, unlike in the case of 'count'. So these may be deemed different phenomena.

Comment: In English and French you "draw" a "drawer". In German you "push" (schieben) a "Schublade".

Comment: @jknappen: I didn't make it an answer because a) it doesn't answer the question,and b) I didn't include any references.